# split and move large cell of table to next page LaTeX

Tags: tables, pdftex, page-breaking, longtable, cell

I need help with `automatically moving rows from one cell of the table to the other page`.  I need a solution for automatic text transfer from one long cell to next page. The solution may seem strange because I have a problem with only a large cell that does not fit on one page. I used `tabular` package, if we used `long-table` package then whole row goes to next page instead of particular long cell. Now,it goes down over `footer` and truncate reaming part, you can check with following `MWE`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}%

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{Caption}\label{tab2}
\begin{tabular}{|p{5cm}|p{4cm}|}
\hline
text & \lipsum  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

We need solution, that will help to break cell and reaming part will go to next page.

Comment: You probably have to rethink what you are doing. Latex never breaks a table cell across a page break only between rows.

Comment: Could you please add more backgound information on why you would need such a table with only one huge row that is longter than a page? Probably some kind of list-like environment is more appropriate for your purpose?

Comment: No, I don't think so. I required similar table as like above with header and footer which will be carry forward on each page. So list will  not be appropriate for my purpose

Comment: Actually, want a table like structure for my problem statement in which 1st row will be of header and next row will contain dynamic size of summary data which can be so huge that it may go on new page. Also, manual rowbreak is not controllable in this case.

Comment: If this had been easy to implement, breakable rows had been implemented in [longtable](https://ctan.org/pkg/longtable) long time ago. You may split a row at page boundary the using a `calstable` from the package [cals](https://ctan.org/pkg/cals), but not automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe [paracol](https://ctan.org/pkg/paracol) can help you. You may also use Heiko Oberdiek’s [pdfcolparcolumns](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfcolparcolumns), if you need stable colours. The `caption` can be typeset with a `\captionof` from the [caption](https://ctan.org/pkg/) package (which I assume you already use). For horizontal rule at the start of the environment, you can use

```
\rule{\dimexpr(2\columnwidth+\columnsep+\columnseprule)}{0.4pt}
```

before the first parallel column. To set the last horizontal rule (at the end) you first have to back up to the left margin before typesetting the rule. I have have use a negative `\hspace` to do that:

```
\hspace{-\dimexpr(\columnwidth+\columnsep+\columnseprule)}
\rule{\dimexpr(2\columnwidth+\columnsep+\columnseprule)}{0.4pt}
```

I have not found a solution for vertical rules at to the left of the first column and to the right of the second column. However, they are unnecessary, so you may left them out.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol, lipsum, caption}
\captionsetup[table]{position=above}


\begin{document}


\captionof{table}{Caption}
\begin{paracol}{2}

\setlength\columnseprule{0.4pt}
\setlength\columnsep{1em}

\rule{\dimexpr(2\columnwidth+\columnsep+\columnseprule)}{0.4pt}

\begin{leftcolumn*}
Test
\end{leftcolumn*}

\begin{rightcolumn}
\lipsum[1]
\end{rightcolumn}

\begin{leftcolumn*}
More test
\end{leftcolumn*}

\begin{rightcolumn}
\lipsum[2-3]
\end{rightcolumn}

\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..Not exactly what I want, but still it will defiantly help me...!!!!